# Please summary of what things break my fast?

Tags: sawm

I looked through other questions. No one asked for a summary on what breaks fast.

what breaks my fast if i do it? If i am fasting and i curse at someone did my fast break?.

Comment: Please mark as answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please [read this](http://islamqa.info/en/38023) for detailed answer.

Comment: Does foreplay count to invalidate fast too?

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, and also it is the extract of the above mentioned link;
1. Eating or drinking
2. Intercourse with the spouse
3. Masturbating
4. Deliberately vomiting
5. Menstruation (of course this is applicable only to women)

Further, you can read Hadiths in the above mentioned link.